# update not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtHidden.Text = Request.QueryString["YKcode"];
    Display();
}

private void Display()
{
    SqlDataReader reader;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=MLC000022;User ID=sa;Password=Adama6DaY; Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + "  dbo.GMYAKU.NAME, " +"FROM " +
                                    "  dbo.GMYAKU " + "   WHERE " +
                                    "  (dbo.GMYAKU.YKCODE = ('" + txtHidden.Text + "'))",con) ;    
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        this.TextBox1.Text = reader["NAME"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {      
        // 読めないので画面を初期化する
     }

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString = null;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    connetionString = ("Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=MLC000022;User ID=sa;Password=redacted; Integrated Security=True");

    string strSQL ;
    strSQL = "UPDATE GMYAKU SET";
    strSQL += " NAME = '" + (TextBox1.Text) + "'";
    strSQL += " WHERE";
    strSQL += " YKCODE= '" + txtHidden.Text + "'";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        // cnn.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
    }

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: you may wish to reformat this and add some context.

Comment: you should read some about sql injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You're using the wrong password in your update statement.  I think the correct password is "Adama6DaY".  But you're silently catching and throwing away the exception thrown on the open so you'll never know.

Comment: @ Paul Mitchell, agree, post it as answer

Comment: exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570580/cant-update-the-data-closed - voting to close

Comment: Your question has already been answered in your original post - please don't just repost again!

Answer (score 0):

It may be something as simple as not having the control in an update panel to refresh with the new data, but without more information/context it is impossible to tell

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the `Request.QueryString["YKcode"];` before assigning value to `txthidden.text` like:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       if(!Request.QueryString["YKcode"].equals("") && Request.QueryString["YKcode"]!=null)
       {
         txtHidden.Text = Request.QueryString["YKcode"];
         Display();
       }
     }
```